# Qt lib for RTD (the replacement for DDE)

Tags: gratis, library, qt

I would like to know if there is any Qt library available for working with RTD ([RealTimeData](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/285339)), the replacement of [DDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange) (the functionality that allow for real time data transfer to e.g. Excel sheets). I did a search on Google and found nothing.

Compatibility with Qt 5 is naturally desired, but the question is open to older versions too.

Btw. any suggestions on libraries for working with DDE are also appreciated (I did found about one such lib, but it's for Qt 3 and quite deprecated).

Comment: For Qt 5? Should it be open source?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul to be honest, the question is truly open. Regarding Qt version, preferentially!